# What is the name of the function $f(k) = \text{max}(k,0)$ on $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: functions, terminology

Let $k\in \mathbb Z$; is there a name for the function $f(k)$ below?
$$
f(k) = \text{max}(k, 0)
$$

Comment: In optimization, the generalized form of your function $f(x,c) = \max(x-c,0)$ is often referred to as a [hinge function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_adaptive_regression_splines#Hinge_functions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be called the "[positive part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts)" of $k$ and denoted $f(k)=k^+$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $|x| = |x|_{+} + |x|_{-}$, where $|x|_{\pm} = \pm x \theta(\pm x)$, where $\theta$ is the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Then your function is the restriction of the function $|x|_{+}$, the *positive part of the absolute value function*, that is, on $\mathbb{Z}$.